# jQuery binding events on ajax retrieved elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that has rows, each of which includes few input fields and a button that does something. Button has class .super-button. Let's say I have 23 rows, and I've just retrieved 24th over AJAX and inserted it bellow, and I want to bind some functionality to it's button on click event.

What I'm doing right now is:

```
$(".super-button").off("click");
$(".super-button").on("click", function(){
    /// Do some awesome functionality
});
```

Is there a better way to bind event to newly inserted element in DOM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can **delegate** the events to the immediate parent that is static.

By doing so you can associate an event just once..

```
$("body").on("click",".super-button", function(){
    /// Do some awesome functionality
});
```

This will make sure you do not need to use **.on()** and **.off()** every single time a new element is created.

NOTE :  Here body can be replaced by the closest static parent , maybe a table in which the rows are present.. I am delegating it using body as I do not know the ,markup.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that if I wrap my buttons with some div container, and use "on" on it by specifying it's children that will trigger event, it will work for all future children added to that container?

Comment: Yup that's right.. Also you do not need to bind it in a new div.. Any static parent element is fine.. Lets say if the table is existent from the start , you can use that as well

Comment: To be more specific: the *delegated* container needs to exist in the html initially, and ajax content can be loaded into it. If you load the container through ajax along with its children, it wont work. This is because what you are doing here is binding the event to the container, not specific items in it (that are added and removed dynamically).

Answer (score 5):

Using [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can attach events to dynamic elements. You bind to the closest static element (or document) specifying the actual intended target element(s) as a secondary parameter.

```
$("document").off("click", ".super-button").on("click", ".super-button", function(){
    /// Do some awesome functionality
});
```

Theoretically you would not need `off()` as your code should be designed to only execute the wire-up code ones.

You execute the attaching of the event ones using the version of `on()` for delegation and then any future element matching the specified selector will have the event attached as expected.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/97wYw/) - Attaching events to dynamically added elements

The DEMO has the following HTML:

```
<button id="addElement" type="button">Add a dynamic element</button>

<div id="container">
    <div class="someElement">Some Element - click me<div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".someElement", function(){
    alert("I have been clicked");
});

$("#addElement").on("click", function() {
    $('<div class="someElement">Another Element - click me too<div>').appendTo($("#container"));
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to bind a `dblclick` event to rows that I add to the already declared table, after receiving the response from an AJAX call. I did not have to do the `.appendTo($("#container"));`.

Can you please though some light on why actually required?

My Sample:

```
$(".divRightDiv table tbody").on("dblclick", ".thisRow", function () {
    //whatever I want to do
});
```

In the AJAX Success, I do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < msg.d.length; i++) {
        if (oddEven == 'even') {
            oddEven = 'odd';
        }
        appendRows += "<tr class='" + oddEven + " thisRow'><td>" + msg.d[i].c_Id + "</td><td>" + msg.d[i].c_Name + "</td></tr>";"</td></tr>");
    }
    $(".tblTableName").append(appendRows);
```